# Creating dynamic radio buttons with React and Meteor and Simple Schema (using pup boilerplate)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, simple-schema

I'm new to reactJS and I'm learning how to use radio buttons using the [pup](http://cleverbeagle.com/pup) boilerplate.

I'm trying to add an input radio code for `icon` to [/imports/ui/components/DocumentEditor/DocumentEditor.js](https://github.com/cleverbeagle/pup/blob/master/imports/ui/components/DocumentEditor/DocumentEditor.js) and this is where I'm at so far:

```
<FormGroup>
  <ControlLabel>Icon</ControlLabel>
  {['mobile', 'tablet', 'laptop', 'tv'].map((el, i) =>
    <Radio 
      ref={icon => (this.icon = icon)} 
      key={i} 
      name="icon" 
      value={el} 
      onChange={e => this.handleRadioSelection(e)}
      inline>
      <i className={`fa fa-3x fa-${el}`}></i>
    </Radio>
  )}
</FormGroup>
```

the handler:

```
handleRadioSelection (e) {
  const { name, value } = e.target;

  this.setState({
    [name]: value
  });
}
```

the schema (using [simpl-schema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simpl-schema))

```
icon: {
  type: String,
  label: 'The icon that better represents the platform.',
  allowedValues: ['mobile', 'tablet', 'laptop', 'tv'],
},
```

I have 2 questions:

1. My array is hard coded and I'd like to import the allowedValues array from the schema, how to do it?
2. My onChange event handler doesn't work, what's missing?

Notes: on the web page I see the radio buttons changing upon radio selection, but the new value doesn't get saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. from the [docs](https://github.com/aldeed/node-simple-schema#allowedvalues) "You can use `schema.getAllowedValuesForKey(key)` to get the allowed values array for a key."
2. You need to bind the function to the `this` context. Read more on the subject e.g. [here](https://toddmotto.com/react-create-class-versus-component/#this-differences). So, in short, either in the constructor do `this.handleRadioSelection = this.handleRadioSelection.bind(this);` or make it an arrow function:

   ```
   handleRadioSelection = (e) => {
     const { name, value } = e.target;

     this.setState({
       [name]: value
     });
   }
   ```

   and use it like:

   ```
   <Radio onChange={this.handleRadioSelection} />
   ```

   For the arrow function to work you need to add the babel plugin for transforming class properties. Do `meteor npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-class-properties` and add the following to your .babelrc

   ```
   {
     "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi tomsp, I was able to complete question 1, by writing `{Documents.schema.getAllowedValuesForKey('icon').map((el, i) =>`, but saving the new `icon` field is still not working. (I used the arrow function you mentioned above and the `onChange={this.handleRadioSelection}`. any ideas?

Comment: can you add a `console.log(name, value)` to the onChange handler to see if the event fires correctly.

Comment: OK, I found a solution for question 2., not sure if it's the recommended way, but I've tested and it works fine. In the `handleSubmit()` function I've changed `icon: this.icon.props.value` to `icon: this.state.icon`!

Comment: haha, dude you didnt show a submitHandler. So the state is set fine, that means my answer is correct. Pls consider accepting it.

Comment: sure, btw, any ideas how display a default value checked?

Comment: using `checked={!this.state ? (!!doc && doc.icon === el) : (this.state && this.state.icon === el)}`